# How to layout form elements

Tags: user-interface, language-agnostic, forms, layout

Are there any good resources for the layout of elements in a form? Possibly large forms as they are common in applications for highly specialised users.

I am talking about choices like:

- go down in columns first, then right to the nex column vs.
- go right in rows first, then down to the next row
- what to do in the presence of especially high and/or wide elements (lists, tables ...)

What aspects are to be considered?

Do the same rules apply for web and conventional rich GUIs?

How does grouping of elements factor in? For example you want the elements concerened with address information stay together.

The perfect answer would take the form of an algorithm producing a reasonable layout for an arbirtrary grouped list of elements to layout.

Comment: GUI design is art, not science.

Comment: If this would be true, the quality of a UI would be completely subjective. I don't think this is true. Why would people use eye trackers and such?

Comment: @Jens: It is subjective. There are people who find one UI intuitive, while other people find the same UI confusing. The best we can do is follow best practices and guidelines (there are few rules when it comes to design) to appeal to, and work for, the broadest audience possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to your local library and pick up Mullet and Sano's "**[Designing Visual Interfaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133033899)**". It is not neccesarily *the* definitive resource, but I find it worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

I have also found these sites useful:

- [UI Pattern Factory](http://uipatternfactory.com/)
- [Interface Hall of Shame](http://homepage.mac.com/bradster/iarchitect/shame.htm)

Comment: +1 for general helpful links on the topic. But I am looking specific for input on how to arange/order elements on a form. Which I couldn't find among the resources.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform what the guidelines are:

- Windows has the [Windows User Experience Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx)
- GNOME has its [Human Interface Guidelines](http://library.gnome.org/devel/hig-book/stable/)
- Mac OS X has [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIntro/XHIGIntro.html)
- Even the iPhone has [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

These are all excellent reads, especially the one for the platform you develop on.

Comment: I don't think so. A form where the fields are arranged in a horizontal first fashion, but the user expects vertical first for whatever reason, will irritate the user, indipendent on the platform used.

Comment: This is true; of course that is an opinion.  Granted, the entire post is subjective.